# Python Rolling Spearman Rank Correlation (between order rank and value rank) from series

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, statistics

This web explain how to calculate rank correlation between two value (Maths rank and English rank):
https://statistics.laerd.com/statistical-guides/spearmans-rank-order-correlation-statistical-guide-2.php

In my case i want to calculate Rolling correlation between Order rank and Value rank in series.

```
seriesData = [81,114,2,32,16,9,7,4,3,26,8,5,3,6,7] #15 length
corr = rolling_corr(seriesData, 4)
```

for example i want to calculate correlation with period 4 so i have to perform 12 windowing. i have to get order and value rank for each window and calculate the correlations.

I Already built the code, but it was too slow, because i have to perform up to 500000 series length. This is the example of first window calculations:

```
 seriesValue  order_rank  value_rank  delta
          81           4           2      4
         114           3           1      4
           2           2           4      4
          32           1           3      4 
Rho Value for 1st window : -0.6000000000000001

 seriesValue  order_rank  value_rank  delta
         114           4           1      9
           2           3           4      1
          32           2           2      0
          16           1           3      4
Rho Value for 2nd window : -0.3999999999999999
```

can you help me to speed up this calculation, Thanks.

```
def rolling_corr(seriesData, window):
    corr = []
    for j in range(len(seriesData)):
        if j < window:
            corr.append(np.nan)
        else:
            data = pd.DataFrame()
            data['seriesValue'] = list(seriesData[j - window:j])

            ###Create Value rank and Order Rank for this window / period
            data = data.reset_index()
            data = data.rename(columns={'index': 'original_index'})
            data = data.sort_values('seriesValue', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
            data = data.reset_index()
            data['index'] = [i + 1 for i in data['index']]
            data = data.rename(columns={'index': 'value_rank'})
            data = data.set_index('original_index')
            data = data.sort_index()
            data['order_rank'] = np.arange(window, 0, -1)
            ####
            # Calculate
            data['delta'] = [(data.loc[ii, 'value_rank'] - data.loc[ii, 'order_rank']) ** 2 for ii in range(len(data))]
            d = data['delta'].sum()
            value = (1 - (6 * d) / (window ** 3 - window))
            #print(data[['seriesValue', 'order_rank', 'value_rank', 'delta']].to_string(index=False))
            #print("Rho Value for window " + str(j) + " : " +str(value))
            corr.append(value)
    return corr
corr = rolling_corr(seriesData, 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

i found that pandas has apply rolling function, this code is faster than my previus operations. approx 0.72 Second for 250 data (10 times faster). I am happy if someone can speed up this code

```
def spearmanCorr(seriesData, n):
    orderRank = pd.Series(range(n, 0, -1))
    def corr(dat):
        valueRank = pd.Series(dat).rank(method='first', ascending=False).reset_index(drop=True)
        deltaSum = ((orderRank-valueRank)**2).sum()
        value = (1 - (6 * deltaSum) / (n ** 3 - n)) * 100
        return value
    return seriesData.rolling(window=n).apply(corr)
```